# Positional encoding without input embedding

Tags: word-embeddings, transformer, attention-mechanism

Does it make sense to use a positional encoding in attention when the input tokens do not go through an embedding layer?

In NLP models, the embedding maps a word to real numbers. `"hello"` might map to some real numbers `[a, b, c]`. Then, after adding positional encoding `[e1, e2, e3]`, the attention layers will see `[a + e1, b + e2, c + e3]`. Since the network has seen this `"hello"` embedding before, it can separate out `[e1, e2, e3]` from `[a, b, c]`, understanding both the token itself and the token's position.

Now imagine we are doing something like detecting particles, where an embedding layer does not make sense. Rather than a set of possible words, the input to the attention layer is from some continuous domain (like the positions of said particles). Can the attention layer still effectively factor out `[e1, e2, e3]` when added to some vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$? How does it know the value of `e1` if `a` could be any value in $\mathbb{R}$?.

I know there are some papers that use transformers without embeddings, but do any show that the positional embedding becomes anything more than sinusoidal noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make a difference if the inputs to the transformer are embeddings or vectors of a different kind. I guess the answer to the question if the attention can factor out the positional vectors is probably yes, but I do not think this is the right question. The question that you should ask is:

- Does the transformer need to know the order/positions of the inputs to do the task well or is the input an unordered set?
- If yes, is the position already encoded in the input?
- If yes, adding position embeddings might help, otherwise, probably not.

The setup that you describe might be similar to vision-and-language models from NLP, such as [UNITER](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.11740) where continuous image-region representations are used as an input to the transformer model. These models do not use traditional additive position embeddings and rather concatenate the image-region representations with the metadata describing the position in the image (x and y coordinates, width, and height).

Pre-trained language models such as [BERT](https://aclanthology.org/N19-1423) use learned position embeddings instead of the original sinusoidal ones. This also might an option for you.